# Identifying the Data transferred from XBee when using Python and python-xbee

Tags: python, arduino, xbee, zigbee

A Xbee Series 2 in Router AT configuration with a potentiometer wiper output connected to XBee's pin 20 `AD0` is supposed to send the analog data every 100 ms. It was set with `ATD02` and `ATIR64`.

A Xbee Series 2 in Coordinator API config is connected to the computer.

Using XCTU terminal, we can see that the Coordinator is constantly receiving `Explicit RX Indicator` frames from the Router. However there are no frames containing the analog data read by `AD0` on the Router XBee.

[image]

[image]

Using Python with the `XBee` module, we also notice the same thing, just `rx_explicit` frames being received and nothing containing the analog data samples!

```
{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x02(', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}

{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x02I', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}

{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\xeb', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}

{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\xce', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}
```

What do you think may have happened? I checked the value at `AD0` by reading it with an Arduino and indeed there is a value to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What frame type were you expecting?  The `rx_explicit` frames will have your I/O data.  You might need to change the `ATAO` (API Options) setting to control whether frames come in as RX Explicit or some other frame type.

Provide a hex dump of the payload on the frames you're receiving, and we can probably figure out the format of the data.  I imagine it will look like the format of an `ATIS` response.